# Should I close my open programs while installing updates?

Tags: upgrade, package-management, updates, software-installation, system

I'm very new to Ubuntu, and Linux in general. In Windows, system updates are generally installed while the computer is shutting down, and completed on the next startup, presumably so that it can access and change protected system files without the chance of user error.

Is this necessary in Ubuntu, or Linux in general? While updates are installing, can I use my computer as I normally would, without having to worry about the update screwing up my system because I was doing something while it was trying to update itself?

I'm running Xubuntu 10.14, but this more of a general question that I'm hoping you guys can answer for most current versions/flavors of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your computer normally while updates are installing. This is because file system works different in Linux than in Windows. In Linux, once file is opened, it is kept in process' memory until process exits, no matter what happened to the opened file during existence of process. For example, you could delete some files process use or even delete the binary of the process itself, the process would continue to run normally. (All data are kept in memory.)

Because of this, no process can be disturbed during updates. But to use updated program you need to restart it (or reboot if kernel was updated).

PS: I presented somewhat simplified view of how file system works, but it should be sufficient to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

no need.

In Linux distros, there can be two type of updates:

1. System updates: where the software components or libraries, linux kernel are updated
2. Software updates: this includes update of software like firefox browser, vlc etc.
   So the point is when you have software updates you need not to worry about the update messing with your open software. If softare whose update you receive will be updated after closing it.

About system updates, some times there may be updates those don't require restart, so these updates won't mess with your system(makers of distros, linux kernel makes sure that you dont have any problem). There may some updates which require restart, so even in this case you don't need to worry since update is applied only after restart.
It can be any type of update, you can apply updates even if you wish to operate your computer for some more time.

this is not much technical answer, but it explains pretty much you need to know as newbie (to a point you need not worry about applying updates anytime).